# EXPECT SCRIPT:procedure being ran before actual code

Tags: stored-procedures, tcl, expect, procedure

I'm creating an expect script to let me use macros in my managing of cisco devices.

after all the connections are done, my script waits for the "#" so I know the user is ready for input.  if I define my procedure AFTER interact, script works fine, but obviously it hasn't been declared yet so the script fails. if I define it BEFORE interact, I time out like it's actually "expecting"

why would this procedure "run" without even being called?

```
proc portSec {port} {
        send "show port interface $int\r"
        expect {
                -nocase -re "(invalid)|(ambig}" {
                        puts "\nInvalid Interface\n"
                        return
                }
                -nocase -re "(\[0-9\]+.\[^ \]+.\[^ \]+):\[^ \]" {
                        set mac $expect_out(1,string)
                }
        }
        ~~~~expect "#" ~~~~~~
        send "show port address \| i $mac\r"
        expect "#"
}

interact {
        "!p" {
                send_user "\nWelcome to macro mode!\nWhich interface would you like to clear port security?: "
                stty echo
                expect_user -re "(.*)\r" {
                        set port $expect_out(1,string)
                }
                stty -echo
                portSec $port
                send "\r"
        }
}
```

Here is the debug

```
expect: does " \r\nYour password will expire in 1 week, 5 days, 3 hours, 
44 minutes and 56 seconds
\r\r\n\r\nHOSTNAME line 1 \r\n\r\nHOSTNAME#" (spawn_id exp4) 
match glob pattern "#"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "#"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) " \r\nYour password will expire in 1 week,
5 days, 3 hours, 44 minutes and 56 seconds\r\r\n\r\nHOSTNAME line 1
n\r\nHOSTNAME#"

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "#"? no
expect: timed out
can't read "mac": no such variable
    while executing
"send "show port address \| i $mac\r""
    (file "./ios.exp" line 78)
```

stepping through the debugger, I tilded "~~~" the line where it's expecting

Comment: Can you post the whole code? Are you sure that the procedure `portSec` haven't called before?

Comment: It is really surprising. Actually, it is not that the proc `portSec` called automatically. Seems like somehow `expect` considers those lines as outside the proc, not inside, which is why this problem happening. It is due to the code `expect {
                -nocase -re "(invalid)|(ambig}" {
                        puts "\nInvalid Interface\n"
                        return
                }
                -nocase -re "(\[0-9\]+.\[^ \]+.\[^ \]+):\[^ \]" {
                        set mac $expect_out(1,string)
                }
        }`.

Comment: Without this `expect`, it is fine. Wondering and trying to find why it is behaving like this. I doubted the square bracket `[`. In order to match the literal `[`, it should be placed as `\\\[`. That also not solving it. Let me try something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh!!! Poor me. How come I missed this mistake!!! :-D

After banging my head for a lot,  found that you have used close braces by mistake in the expect statement.

```
        -nocase -re "(invalid)|(ambig}" {
```

Changing it to bracket, solves this issue. :-)

```
proc portSec {port} {
        send "show port interface $int\r"
        expect {
                -nocase -re "(invalid)|(ambig)" {
                        puts "\nInvalid Interface\n"
                        return
                }
                -nocase -re {\[0-9\]+.\[^ \]+.\[^ \]+):\[^ \]} {
                        set mac $expect_out(1,string)
                }
        }
        expect "#";#
        send "show port address \| i $mac\r"
        expect "#"
}
```

It all makes sense now. But, why `Expect` didn't throw any error as such? Then Why it has to  accept the remaining part of braces as correct one ?

Well, Because of the misplaced close brace, `Expect` assumes that the it closes the first expect statement. The code segment remaining are

```
    # two code segments enclosed in braces 
    # 'Expect' assumes these two as pattern-action pair
    # which is why no errors thrown for these blocks.
    {
        puts "\nInvalid Interface\n"
        return
    }
    -nocase -re "(\[0-9\]+.\[^ \]+.\[^ \]+):\[^ \]" {
        set mac $expect_out(1,string)
    }
};# This one closes the proc 'portSec'
####### Below code is now in global scope #########3
expect "#"; # Now, wait for '#'
# Send this command now, but wait...
# I don't know about the variable 'mac'
send "show port address \| i $mac\r"
expect "#"
```

Thereby throwing the error message as `can't read "mac": no such variable`.

Comment: wow, can't believe it was because of a simple mistype. thanks a lot for your help! and also the extra explanation.

Comment: one more quick question for you, after I `interact` it seems like `expect_user` doesn't echo any more.... my current fix is `stty echo` and `stty -echo` but that lets the user do funky things with the arrow keys.

Answer (score 0):

Final product:

```
#port security clear feature
proc clearPortSec {} {
        send_user "\n=====\nWelcome to the Port Security Macro!!!!!\nWhich interface would you like to clear port security?: "
        #interact seems to turn of user echoing... turn it back on so the user can make changes
        stty echo
        expect_user -re "(.*)\r" {
                set port $expect_out(1,string)
        }
        stty -echo
        #send ctrl+u to clear the line, and send ctrl+z so we know we are in enable mode
        send "\025\032\r"
        expect "#"
        #verify it is explicitly an access port, if not we don't do the operations to prevent trunks from being shut
        send "sho run int $port \| i switchport mode access\r"
        expect {
                -nocase -re "\r\n\[ \]*switchport mode access\[ \]*\r\n.*#" {
                        send "\rshow port interface $port\r"
                        expect {
                                #grabs offending mac address on this port
                                -nocase -re "(\[0-9\]+.\[^ \]+.\[^ \]+):\[^ \]" {
                                        set mac $expect_out(1,string)
                                        expect "#"
                                        #finds where switch learned the offending mac
                                        send "show port address \| i $mac\r"
                                        expect {
                                                #case where switch learned mac from another interface
                                                -nocase -re "sticky +(\[^ \]+)" {
                                                        set offendport $expect_out(1,string)
                                                        puts "\n=====\nMac was found on interface $offendport. Clearing $offendport\n====="
                                                        #clear port mac was found on
                                                        expect "#"
                                                        send "\rconf t\r"; expect "#"
                                                        send "interface $offendport\r"; expect "#"
                                                        send "no switchport port-security mac-address sticky\r"; expect "#"
                                                        send "switchport port-security mac-address sticky\r"; expect "#"
                                                        send "shut\r"; expect "#"
                                                        send "no shut\r;" expect "#"
                                                        #switch to original port
                                                        send "interface $port\r"; expect "#"
                                                        send "no switchport port-security mac-address sticky\r"; expect "#"
                                                        send "switchport port-security mac-address sticky\r"; expect "#"
                                                        send "shut\r"; expect "#"
                                                        send "no shut\r"; expect "#"
                                                        #end all operation and print status of each port
                                                        send "end\r"; expect "#"
                                                        send "wr\r"; expect "#"
                                                        puts "\n=====\nSleeping a few seconds..\nPrevious port will NOT be shut. Please shut if necessary\n====="
                                                        send "show int $offendport status\r"; expect "#"
                                                        send "show int $port status\r"; expect "#"
                                                }
                                                #case where switch never learned mac
                                                "#" {
                                                        puts "\n=====\nMac is no where else on the switch, clearing existing sticky mac from $port\n====="
                                                        send "\rconf t\r"; expect "#"
                                                        send "interface $port\r"; expect "#"
                                                        send "no switchport port-security mac-address sticky\r"; expect "#"
                                                        send "switchport port-security mac-address sticky\r"; expect "#"
                                                        send "shut\r"; expect "#"
                                                        send "no shut\r"; expect "#"
                                                        send "end\r"; expect "#"
                                                        send "wr\r"; expect "#"
                                                        puts "\n=====\nSleeping a few seconds..\n====="
                                                        sleep 3
                                                        send "show int $port status\r"
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }
                #if we get back '%' - input error, if we get back '#' switchport mode access doesn't exist
                -re "\[%#\]" {
                        puts "\n=====\nInvalid Interface\nThis script ignores all interfaces that don't have \"Switchport mode access\"\n====="
                        send "\r"
                }
        }
}


# Don't check keys
spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $username\@$hostname

expect {
        "assword:" {
                interact -o -re "\[#>\]" return {
                        puts "\nLog in Complete"
                }
        }
        timeout {
                puts "=====\n$hostname timeout\n====="
                exit 1
        }
        eof {
                exit 1
        }
}
send "\n"
expect "#"
set timeout -1
interact {
        -re "!\[Hh\]" {
                puts "\n=====\nMacro list\n=====\nPort Security: !p\n\n"
                send "\r"
                expect "#"
        }
        "!p" { clearPortSec }
}
```